# Exclude a path prefix from congito cookie check AWSELBAuthSessionCookie

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have multiple single paged angular and react application all comes under one domain
Let us `app1.example.com/employee` , `app1.example.com/movies`

The applications are deployed in `Fargate ecs Containers`

Now I have login redirect any URL I invoke for SSO, `signin.example.com` which is a sub domain

Now cognito has it own domain `app1-12345678.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize`

My question is: I would like to prevent this sso redirect for all `/logout`, so that I can clear server side cookies

I can see this documentation [Logout Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html) but it goes congnito and again comes back to my own application code

But my application still requires a valid `AWSELBAuthSessionCookie`, which is already expired

Is any of you guys had this issue and solved it ? please let me know
By the way I am calling `/logout` via AJAX